# Error deploying a crystal report application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I post this thread because, i'm in despair.

I have developped a C# application which uses Crystal Report to generate a *.doc file. The application works on my developpement station but i can't make it work on client station.

When i am executing the application on client station, the application crashes with the following message : "MyApplicationName.exe stop working". I have installed Visual Studio on the client station for viewing the line crash the application and the line is : `rpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, destinatedPath);`
The line is extracted from this code :

```
ReportDocument rpt =  rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(rptPath);
rpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, destinatedFilePath);
```

When i debug the application with Visual Studio, the error is :

```
0x00000000 in MyApplicationName.exe : 
0xC0000005: Access Violation
```

I deployed my application with **Installshield**. I used **MergeModule** to add **SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework** in the prerequisites. 
Moreover, i included to prerequisites **Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Full**  and **Windows Installer 4.5 for Windows Vista(x86)**

My developpement configuration and client configuration : **Windows 7 64 bits**, **Net Framework 4.5**, **SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 13.0.15** , **Visual Studio 2012**.

I am on the problem for 4 days so i need your help.

Thank you in advance for your help.